# Recommended Way of Deploying Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

What is the recommended way of deploying Azure Key Vault:

1. One Key Vault per environment e.g. Production, Test etc.
2. One Key Vault used globally.

If I want to automate creation of Azure resources using ARM templates, it seems the second method is preferable. However, storing Test and Production secrets together could cause mistakes to happen unless you use some kind of naming scheme for secret names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official recommendation is that a Key Vault is not shared across environments.

> Don't use prefixes on key vault secrets to place secrets for multiple apps into the same key vault or to place environmental secrets (for example, development versus production secrets) into the same vault. We recommend that different apps and development/production environments use separate key vaults to isolate app environments for the highest level of security.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1#create-prefixed-key-vault-secrets-and-load-configuration-values-key-name-prefix-sample)

We deploy them through ARM templates, and have not really had trouble.
Some PowerShell (or other) scripts may be needed to set secrets after ARM deployment.

Comment: Those PowerShell scripts you mention in passing is [my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012377/can-secrets-from-objects-created-in-arm-templates-get-auto-added-to-key-vault).

Comment: Here is the documentation on [How to set/create secrets in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add to this answer. I do agree that each application or process should have it's own Key Vault in a single region and absolutely different ones per environment.

In the end it really depends what you are using Key Vault for and how comfortable you are with managing Key Vault.  Yes, [Key Vault is replicated to a secondary region by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-disaster-recovery-guidance); however, if you are using or planning to use Key Vault for VM Disk encryption [it does not cross regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disk-encryption-key-vault) So if your discs will be stored in multiple regions you will need to have a separate Key Vault in each region.