# Can Secrets From Objects Created in ARM Templates Get Auto Added to Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

If I have an Azure ARM template that can create:

- Azure Container Registry
- Azure Key Vault

Is there a way for the username and password for the Azure Container Registry to be automatically be added to the Azure Key Vault using ARM templates?

Is there some way to refer to the Azure Container Registry username and password secrets in ARM templates for this purpose?

**UPDATE**

@EdBoykin's answer is correct, this is what I ended up with:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('key_vault_name'), '/AzureContainerRegistryKey1')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "value": "[listCredentials(resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', parameters('container_registry_name')), '2017-10-01').passwords[0].value]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('key_vault_name'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/', parameters('container_registry_name'))]"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muhammad,
To create the secrets in KeyVault you will need to create an ARM template that looks something like this. Make sure to update the 'dependson' section so this resource depends on your ACR being created first. The username is going to be the ACR resource name. So, whatever you set that to in your ARM script, you can store in your key vault as a key vault secret.

For the passwords, or keys, this is what you do. Here is a sample template for adding a KeyVault secret

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '/{YourACRKey1SecretName}')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "value": "[listCredentials(resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', parameters('YourACRName')), '2017-10-01').passwords[0].value]"
  },
  "dependsOn": []
}
```

{YourACRKey1SecretName} should be changed to the secret name for your ACR Key1 value.

To set the other key in your keyvault, create another key vault secret resource with a new name and use this for the value:

For Key 2

```
[listCredentials(resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', parameters('YourACRName')), '2017-10-01').passwords[1].value]
```

Comment: How did you determine what this had to be: `.passwords[1].value`? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Can I also get the server path and username, or do I have to rely on knowing the naming convention?

Comment: When I was trying to do this I had to wing it and trial and error to find how to access the keys but I've since found this on github [ACR Faq] (https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md)

Comment: The username is going to be set to the name you gave the resource, so in my example there is a parameter `parameters('YourACRName')`  The value of that parameter is going to be the username