# How to Create Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-aks

I've written an ARM template to deploy Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). However, I'm unable to find a way to automate the creation of the service principal client ID and secret.

Is there a way I can create the service principal in an ARM template and store the client ID and secret in Azure Key Vault, as I've learned to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012377/can-secrets-from-objects-created-in-arm-templates-get-auto-added-to-key-vault/53064243)?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environment": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the environment."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    // Azure Kubernetes Service
    "kubernetes_name": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Managed Cluster resource."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_location": {
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The location of AKS resource."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_dnsPrefix": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Optional DNS prefix to use with hosted Kubernetes API server FQDN."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_osDiskSizeGB": {
      "defaultValue": 0,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Disk size (in GB) to provision for each of the agent pool nodes. This value ranges from 0 to 1023. Specifying 0 will apply the default disk size for that agentVMSize."
      },
      "maxValue": 1023,
      "minValue": 0,
      "type": "int"
    },
    "kubernetes_osType": {
      "allowedValues": [
        "Linux"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Linux",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The type of operating system."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_agentCount": {
      "defaultValue": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The number of agent nodes for the cluster."
      },
      "maxValue": 50,
      "minValue": 1,
      "type": "int"
    },
    "kubernetes_agentVMSize": {
      "defaultValue": "Standard_D2_v2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the Virtual Machine."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_maxPods": {
      "defaultValue": 30,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Maximum number of pods that can run on a node."
      },
      "type": "int"
    },
    "kubernetes_servicePrincipalClientId": {
      "defaultValue": null,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Client ID (used by cloudprovider)"
      },
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "kubernetes_servicePrincipalClientSecret": {
      "defaultValue": null,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Service Principal Client Secret."
      },
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "kubernetes_kubernetesVersion": {
      "defaultValue": "1.7.7",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The version of Kubernetes."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_enableHttpApplicationRouting": {
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "boolean flag to turn on and off of http application routing"
      },
      "type": "bool"
    },
    "kubernetes_networkPlugin": {
      "allowedValues": [
        "azure",
        "kubenet"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "kubenet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Network plugin used for building Kubernetes network."
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kubernetes_enableRBAC": {
      "defaultValue": true,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "boolean flag to turn on and off of RBAC"
      },
      "type": "bool"
    },
    "kubernetes_enableOmsAgent": {
      "defaultValue": true,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "boolean flag to turn on and off of omsagent addon"
      },
      "type": "bool"
    },
    // Azure Log Analytics
    "log_analytics_location": {
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the region for your OMS workspace"
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "log_analytics_workspaceName": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the name of the OMS workspace"
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "log_analytics_workspaceId": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specify the resource id of the OMS workspace"
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "log_analytics_sku": {
      "allowedValues": [
        "free",
        "standalone",
        "pernode"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "free",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Select the SKU for your workspace"
      },
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "comments": "Azure Kubernetes Service",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-31",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'WorkspaceDeployment')]"
      ],
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
      "location": "[parameters('kubernetes_location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('kubernetes_name')]",
      "properties": {
        "kubernetesVersion": "[parameters('kubernetes_kubernetesVersion')]",
        "enableRBAC": "[parameters('kubernetes_enableRBAC')]",
        "dnsPrefix": "[parameters('kubernetes_dnsPrefix')]",
        "addonProfiles": {
          "httpApplicationRouting": {
            "enabled": "[parameters('kubernetes_enableHttpApplicationRouting')]"
          },
          "omsagent": {
            "enabled": "[parameters('kubernetes_enableOmsAgent')]",
            "config": {
              "logAnalyticsWorkspaceResourceID": "[parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId')]"
            }
          }
        },
        "agentPoolProfiles": [
          {
            "name": "agentpool",
            "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('kubernetes_osDiskSizeGB')]",
            "osType": "[parameters('kubernetes_osType')]",
            "count": "[parameters('kubernetes_agentCount')]",
            "vmSize": "[parameters('kubernetes_agentVMSize')]",
            "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
            "maxPods": "[parameters('kubernetes_maxPods')]"
          }
        ],
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "ClientId": "[parameters('kubernetes_servicePrincipalClientId')]",
          "Secret": "[parameters('kubernetes_servicePrincipalClientSecret')]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkPlugin": "[parameters('kubernetes_networkPlugin')]"
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "comments": "Azure Log Analytics (Container Insights)",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "name": "SolutionDeployment",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "resourceGroup": "[split(parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId'),'/')[4]]",
      "subscriptionId": "[split(parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId'),'/')[2]]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
              "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
              "location": "[parameters('log_analytics_location')]",
              "name": "[concat('ContainerInsights', '(', split(parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId'),'/')[8], ')')]",
              "properties": {
                "workspaceResourceId": "[parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId')]"
              },
              "plan": {
                "name": "[concat('ContainerInsights', '(', split(parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId'),'/')[8], ')')]",
                "product": "[concat('OMSGallery/', 'ContainerInsights')]",
                "promotionCode": "",
                "publisher": "Microsoft"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', 'WorkspaceDeployment')]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "comments": "Azure Log Analytics",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "name": "WorkspaceDeployment",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "resourceGroup": "[split(parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId'),'/')[4]]",
      "subscriptionId": "[split(parameters('log_analytics_workspaceId'),'/')[2]]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
              "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
              "location": "[parameters('log_analytics_location')]",
              "name": "[parameters('log_analytics_workspaceName')]",
              "properties": {
                "sku": {
                  "name": "[parameters('log_analytics_sku')]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "controlPlaneFQDN": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/', parameters('kubernetes_name'))).fqdn]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot create Service Principals in ARM templates.

I create them using PowerShell scripts and then either pass the relevant properties in to the ARM Template as parameters, or push them in to KeyVault and reference them from KeyVault where supported by the relevant ARM Template.